# Can I change the battery displayed by wingpanel-indicator-power?

Tags: wingpanel

My Thinkpad T460 has both an internal and external battery. Wingpanel is showing the internal battery on the top dock as 100% , but actually I want the other one showing, as the system shuts down anyway once the main battery hits 0%. So my at a glace battery status is useless unless I click down to see the second battery

[image: My battery]

Is there a way I can edit a file to change which battery is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The repository for that indicator: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-power
There already seems to be an open issue on this: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-power/issues/13